# add borders around each element in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a JPanel and I'm adding 25 JPanels to the inside in a grid. I want a border around each panel so you can clearly distinguish between each element.  Padding would work as well.  The way I'm adding panels to the board if I try to add a border it will apply it to the larger panel containing the elements instead.

```
public class LightsOutView
```

{
    GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(5, 5);

```
// Creates layout of the GUI
public LightsOutView ()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Lights Out");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setContentPane(makeContents());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * Creates the blank game board. Returns the panel
 * 
 * @return JPanel
 */
public JPanel makeContents ()
{
    // Create a panel to hold the 5x5 grid
    JPanel board = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 5));
    board.setLayout(experimentLayout);

    // Add the components to the panel
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        board.add(new JPanel()).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    }

    // Return the panel
    return board;
}
```

}

How do I add a border around each element. Will I need to change how I'm adding panels to the grid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## One way:

Change your GridLayout to something like:

```
GridLayout experimentLayout = new GridLayout(5, 5, gap, gap);
```

where gap is some small int value, say 1 to 3 (for pixels). Then give the background container a background color, and it will show through the gaps. You'll also want to give the background JPanel a line border with the same gap width.

For example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GridWithBorders extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIDES = 6;
    private static final int SIDE_LENGTH = 60;
    private static final int GAP = 3;
    private static final Color BG = Color.BLACK;
    private static final Color CELL_COLOR = Color.GREEN.darker();

    public GridWithBorders() {
        setBackground(BG);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES, GAP, GAP));
        Dimension prefSize = new Dimension(SIDE_LENGTH, SIDE_LENGTH);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIDES; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIDES; j++) {
                JPanel cell = new JPanel();
                cell.setBackground(CELL_COLOR);
                cell.setPreferredSize(prefSize);
                add(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        GridWithBorders mainPanel = new GridWithBorders();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridWithBorders");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect! I guess I didn't recognize that part of the documentation for GridLayout.

Comment: @ZacharyKing: see example above